# querying methods in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, methods, laravel-5, relationships

I am trying to figure out something in Laravel.
I have a model 'Phone' and a method countproducts().
Every model 'Phone' has many 'Product'.

I use countproducts() to count the products a phone has.

```
 $phones=Phone::where(function($query){
  if(isset($min_weight) && isset($max_weight)){
      $query-> where('weight','>=',$min_weight);
      $query-> where('weight','<=',$max_weight);
  }
```

This is how i am querying the phones by now.

Is it possible to query and show only phones with lets say more than 50 products??

Thanks in advance

EDIT: Phone.php

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Phone extends Model {

    public function productnum()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
    }

    public function productStore()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Store');
    }

    public function category(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
    }

    public function minprice(){
        return $this->productnum->min('newprice');
    }

    public function maxprice(){


         return $this->productnum->max('newprice');
        }
    }
```

Product.php

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model {

    public function manufacturer(){
        return $this->hasOne('manufacturer');
    }

    public function phone(){
        return $this->belongsto('App\Phone');
    }

    public function category(){
        return $this->belongsto('App\Category');
    }
    public function store(){
        return $this->belongsto('App\Store');
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Straight from the [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#querying-relations).

```
$phones = Phone::has('products', '>=', 50)->get();
```

You should be able to put before the `get()` your `where()` clauses.

Comment: i am getting error `Call to a member function getRelationCountQuery() on a non-object` when i make that change ;/ i googled it without much information related to that error

Comment: May be there should be `contrproducts` instead of `products`?

Comment: Thanks @AnatoliyArkhipov for trying to help me out. :) What's contrproducts? I don't have anything similar in my code

Comment: In your question you says `I have a model 'Phone' and a method countproducts()`

Comment: Oh lol, my mistake, sorry. It's `count` products, inattentively read

Comment: So, in this case, I think the Matthias's code should be correct. Can you please provide code of your `Phone` model?

Comment: Hello @AnatoliyArkhipov , thanks again. I edited the post with the code of the 2 models.

Comment: Change `productnum` function to `products` and my example should work. That's probably the naming convention for relationships. I don't know why you would name it `productnum`.

Comment: Thanks guys for trying to help me out :) Unfortunately i am still getting the same error for some reason. So do you think that i has something to do with the relationships?